# SQL Server - Alterar informação em um campo texto (REPLACE não funciona)

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

[image: Campo texto em tabela]

Olá pessoal. Tenho uma tabela com um campo TEXTO. Preciso alterar uma informacao dentro deste campo texto só que nao estou conseguindo. A funcao REPLACE funciona em um campo varchar, mas nao funciona dentro do campo texto.

Por example: 
Eu tenho um registro onde este campo contem a seguinte informacao: "INFO:Alfa,Beta,Gama;CPPC-TM:0x3453;ALGOMAIS"
Preciso alterar esse valor "CPPC-TM" para "NEWINFO".
O resiltado final deve ser: "INFO:Alfa,Beta,Gama;NEWINFO:0x3453;ALGOMAIS"

Existe uma forma de fazer isso via sql?

Já tentei:

```
update MYTABELE
set orgsalkeyfil = replace(orgsalkeyfil, 'CPPC-TM', 'NEWINFO');
```

Mas retorna sempre um erro.
[image: Mensagem de erro]

Se executo o mesmo script em um campo varchar ele executa sem problema.

Comment: Se o tamanho da coluna não for muito grande, você pode converter, utilizando [CAST](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) para `varchar` e depois substituir.

Comment: Se for o caso pode fazer cast para (n)VARCHAR(MAX), só que tome cuidado de colocar um WHERE limitando os casos em que o campo não exceda o tamanho do VARCHAR (eram uns 8k acho), senão vai truncar os dados. Em NVARCHAR acredito não ter esse problema, mas é bom verificar.- Seria bom alguem testar/confirmar e postar algo nesse sentido (cc @ValdeirPsr). `REPLACE(CAST(orgsalkeyfil AS varchar(MAX)) ,'original', 'substituido')`

Comment: Avalie também o uso de UPDATETEXT ou STUFF()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se ajuda.

```
declare @MYTABELE table
(
  id int,
  orgsalkeyfil text 
)

insert into @MYTABELE values(1,'INFO:Alfa,Beta,Gama;CPPC-TM:0x3453;ALGOMAIS');

UPDATE @MYTABELE
SET orgsalkeyfil = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(orgsalkeyfil as NVarchar(4000)),'CPPC-TM', 'NEWINFO') AS NText)
WHERE orgsalkeyfil LIKE '%CPPC-TM%' 

select * from @MYTABELE
```

Você pode especificar ainda o `and  DATALENGTH(orgsalkeyfil) < 4000`, caso tenha campos com dados muito grandes.

[Referencia 1.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4341677/2740371)
[Referencia 2.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1188/how-to-get-length-of-text-ntext-and-image-columns-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado @Marconcílio.

O seu código me atendeu. Entre uns 50k registros, apenas 9 tinham o campo com mais de 4000 caracteres.

Eu desenvolvi o código abaixo que nao importa o tamanho do campo, mas ele demora muito rodando/processando.

```
DECLARE @ptrval binary(16);
DECLARE @insert_offset int;
DECLARE @id int;
SET @id = 1;
WHILE (select count(*) from torgsalkey where torgsalkey.orgsalkeyfil like N'%CPPC01PC1-LCM%') > 0
BEGIN
    if (select count(*) from torgsalkey where torgsalkey.orgsalkeyfil like N'%CPPC01PC1-LCM%' and orgsalkeyid = @id) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ptrval = TEXTPTR(orgsalkeyfil) FROM torgsalkey WHERE orgsalkeyid = @id
        SELECT
          @insert_offset = PATINDEX(N'%CPPC01PC1-LCM%', orgsalkeyfil) - 1
        FROM torgsalkey
        WHERE orgsalkeyid = @id

        WHILE @insert_offset > -1
        BEGIN
          UPDATETEXT torgsalkey.orgsalkeyfil @ptrval @insert_offset 13 'CPPC01';
          SELECT
            @insert_offset = PATINDEX(N'%CPPC01PC1-LCM%', orgsalkeyfil) - 1
          FROM torgsalkey
         WHERE orgsalkeyid = @id
         print @insert_offset
        END
    END
    SET @id = @id + 1;
END
```

Comment: Legal. talvez um cursor seja melhor que você fazer esse monte de select.  ...

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Nao conhecia o "cursor".
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql